# XML persistence more than one item?

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xml-serialization

Hey I have the following code to Store the data from a list into a XML file, However when I add a 2nd Item to the list it just overwrites the first one in XML so there is only ever one Item in the XML file, How can I solve this

class

```
public class Visits
{
/*
 * This class represents a single appointment
 */

    private string Customer_Name;
    private string Customer_Address;
    private DateTime Arrival_Time;
    private string Visit_Type;
    private Double Lat1;
    private Double Long1;
    //Private methods. Note the use of DateTime to store arrival time

    public string name{
        //Description property
        set { Customer_Name = value; }
        get {return Customer_Name;}
    }

    public string address
    {//Time property
        set { Customer_Address = value; }
        get { return Customer_Address; }
    }

    public DateTime arrival
    {   //Duration property
        set { Arrival_Time = value; }
        get { return Arrival_Time; }
    }

    public string type
    {
        set { Visit_Type = value; }
        get { return Visit_Type; }
    }

    public Double Lat
    {
        //Description property
        set { Lat1 = value; }
        get { return Lat1; }
    }

    public Double Lon1
    {
        //Description property
        set { Long1 = value; }
        get { return Long1; }
    } 
    public override string ToString()
    {   //Return a String representing the object
        return Visit_Type + "     " + Customer_Name + " " + Customer_Address + " " + Arrival_Time.ToString() + " " + "Latitude  " + Lat1 + " " + "Longitude  " + Long1;
    }
}
```

}

then the list

```
class List
{
/*
 * This object represents the List. It has a 1:M relationship with the Visit class
 */

    private List<Visits> visits = new List<Visits>();
    //List object use to implement the relationshio with Visits

    public void addVisits(Visits vis)
    {
        //Add a new Visit to the List
        visits.Add(vis);
    }

    public List<String> listVisits()
    {//Generate a list of String objects, each one of which represents a Visit in List.

        List<String> listVisits = new List<string>();
        //This list object will be populated with Strings representing the Visits in the lists

        foreach (Visits vis in visits)
        {
            String visAsString = vis.ToString();
            //Get a string representing the current visit object

            listVisits.Add(visAsString);
            //Add the visit object to the List
        }

        return listVisits;
        //Return the list of strings
    }

    public Visits getVisits(int index)
    {
        //Return the visit object at the <index> place in the list

        int count = 0;
        foreach (Visits vis in visits)
        {
            //Go through all the visit objects
            if (index == count)
                //If we're at the correct point in the list...
                return vis;
            //exit this method and return the current visit
            count++;
            //Keep counting
        }
        return null;
        //Return null if an index was entered that could not be found
    }
}
```

}

then the code to add

```
            thePickup.name = txtCustName.Text;
            thePickup.address = txtCustAddress.Text;
            thePickup.arrival = DateTime.Parse(txtArrival.Text);
            thePickup.Dname = txtDeliveryName.Text;
            thePickup.Daddress = txtDaddress.Text;
            thePickup.Lat = Double.Parse(txtLat.Text);
            thePickup.Lon1 = Double.Parse(txtLong.Text);
            thePickup.type = "Pickup";
            //Update thePickup object to reflect any changes made by the user

            XmlSerializer SerializerObj = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Pickups));

        using (TextWriter WriteFileStream = new StreamWriter(@"Pickup.xml", true))
        {
            SerializerObj.Serialize(WriteFileStream, thePickup);
        }
```

When I add a new entry It just changes the format of the original entry

Comment: Is the File beeing overwrited the issue, or multiple nodes with the same name, beeing overwrited is the issue ?

Comment: @MarcelloGrechiLins The issue is say for example I have a Visit with the deatails 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 ect and I then add a new one with the details of 2,2,2,2 ect when I open the XML it has only 2,2,2,2,2 ect and it SHOULD show both

Comment: So the problems are Both.
The answer of @Valtasarlll will solve the StreamWritter overwriting the File everytime you create a StreamWriter.

My Answer will help you to avoid creating nodes with the same name, overwriting each other. Check both Answers, i hope that helps

Comment: @MarcelloGrechiLins Thanks, I will look at both, I will try to get Valtasarlll answer to work then I will look at yours

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use [XPath](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/default.asp) supported libraries to handle XML Assembling and creation.

As you are using C# i would recomend [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) for handling the "Parsing" thing.

In order to build the XML, [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9494/Manipulate-XML-data-with-XPath-and-XmlDocument-C) is a good source for learning how to do so using XPath.

You can also use the native XMLDocument class from C# with in your case may be more useful if you are building it without any parsing logic before.

Take a look [here](http://csharp.net-tutorials.com/xml/using-xpath-with-the-xmldocument-class/)

**XPath Sample:**

Here is an XPath sample that would help you to avoid overriding the actual node in the XML File.

```
CreateTag("//NODE1/NODE2", "TAG_NAME", tagContent);


    private void CreateTag(string xPath, string tag, string tagContent)
    {
        XmlNode node = _xml.SelectSingleNode(xPath);
        XmlElement element = _xml.CreateElement(tag);

        element.InnerText = tagContent;
        node.AppendChild(element);
    }
```

In case your set has multiple nodes with the same name :

```
CreateTag("//SINTEGRA//SEARCH//RECORDS//RECORD[last()]", kv.Key, kv.Value);
```

Where `last()` is a XPath method that is implemented by most of .dlls that returns the index to the lastnode + 1 so that your node will be inserted after the last created one

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
using(TextWriter WriteFileStream = new StreamWriter(@"Pickups.xml", true))
{
    SerializerObj.Serialize(WriteFileStream, thePickup);
}
```

instead.

The `boolean true` parameter means that the StreamWriter will `append` the next written block to the existing file, instead of overwriting it

Otherwise, your code overwrites **Pickups.xml** file each time. And don't forget to close WriteFileStream  object.

I tried to reproduce your case:

```
    public class Pickups
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string address { get; set; }
        public string Dname { get; set; }
        public string Daddress { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
        public DateTime arrival { get; set; }
        public DateTime Lat { get; set; }
        public DateTime Lon1 { get; set; }
    }
```

```
class Program
{


    static void Main()
    {
        Pickups thePickup = new Pickups();
        thePickup.name = "nameProp";
        thePickup.address = "addressProp";
        thePickup.arrival = DateTime.Now;
        thePickup.Dname = "txtDeliveryName";
        thePickup.Daddress = "txtDaddress";
        thePickup.Lat = DateTime.Now;
        thePickup.Lon1 = DateTime.Now;
        thePickup.type = "Pickup";
        //Update thePickup object to reflect any changes made by the user

        XmlSerializer SerializerObj = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Pickups));

        using (TextWriter WriteFileStream = new StreamWriter(@"Pickups.xml", true))
        {
            SerializerObj.Serialize(WriteFileStream, thePickup);
        }

        Pickups thePickup1 = new Pickups();
        thePickup1.name = "nameProp2";
        thePickup1.address = "addressProp2";
        thePickup1.arrival = DateTime.Now;
        thePickup1.Dname = "txtDeliveryName2";
        thePickup1.Daddress = "txtDaddress2";
        thePickup1.Lat = DateTime.Now;
        thePickup1.Lon1 = DateTime.Now;
        thePickup1.type = "Pickup2";

        using (TextWriter WriteFileStream = new StreamWriter(@"Pickups.xml", true))
        {
            SerializerObj.Serialize(WriteFileStream, thePickup1);
        }
    }

}
```

And in **Pickups.xml** file I get expected result(2 entities):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Pickups xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <name>nameProp</name>
  <address>addressProp</address>
  <Dname>txtDeliveryName</Dname>
  <Daddress>txtDaddress</Daddress>
  <type>Pickup</type>
  <arrival>2012-12-05T15:30:37.809487+01:00</arrival>
  <Lat>2012-12-05T15:30:37.810487+01:00</Lat>
  <Lon1>2012-12-05T15:30:37.810487+01:00</Lon1>
</Pickups><?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Pickups xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <name>nameProp2</name>
  <address>addressProp2</address>
  <Dname>txtDeliveryName2</Dname>
  <Daddress>txtDaddress2</Daddress>
  <type>Pickup2</type>
  <arrival>2012-12-05T15:30:37.989487+01:00</arrival>
  <Lat>2012-12-05T15:30:37.989487+01:00</Lat>
  <Lon1>2012-12-05T15:30:37.989487+01:00</Lon1>
</Pickups>
```

Are you sure you fixed all parts of your program? Maybe you write to the same file from different places in your code?

Comment: @Valtasarlll This seems like a good way to do it, however When I do this, It doesn't work, For some reason When I add a new one, all It does is change the layout of the first one, or nothing, Any Idea?

Comment: @TAM Try to close WriteFileStream object after writing (like in edited version), this is anyway necessary. Otherwise, this solution should work.

Comment: @Valtasarlll It is still not working I will edit the code in the post to show what I have now, And what the XML file is doing

Comment: @TAM I tried to reproduce your case, and it works for me. Check the edited answer.

Comment: @Valtasarlll Thanks, It still isn't happening for me and I don't know why, thanks for trying to help though.  The only difference  can see is that Mine doesn't have thePickup, and thePickup1 as each time it is added to a list via the textbox contents

Comment: @Valtasarlll I have edited my original post to show the full structure of my list and class if that helps

Answer (score 0):

Do not serialize a single element but a list:

```
 List<Pickups> list = new List<Pickups>();

 foreach ( var pickup in ... )
    list.Add( pickup );

 ...
 XmlSerializer SerializerObj = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Pickups>));

 TextWriter WriteFileStream = new StreamWriter(@"Pickups.xml");
 SerializerObj.Serialize( WriteFileStream, list );
```